# BASH: i can echo string + grep + sed, but how to add more strings on the same line?

Tags: bash, sed, newline, printf, echo

Asking a question here is always my last resort. I tried everything even the most embarrassing code so i'm confused on explaining what i tried with no success. I have:

```
echo $output | grep -i -m 1 "Time:" | sed 's/.*\s\([0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*\).time.*/\1/'
```

it outputs:

```
23:25:31
```

Easy.

But i'd like to add one more string to the end, like " , $year" - so that i have:

```
23:25:31 , 2013
```

The problem is that whatever i tried (printf, -n, -e, -ne, brackets, quotes, |, ;, &, /r, etc.) gives an error or goes to a new line anyway.

Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What does the input look like?

Comment: thanks Carl, but that other guy has solved the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
time=$(echo $output | grep -i -m 1 "Time:" | sed 's/.*\s\([0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*\).time.*/\1/')
echo "The time is ${time}, 2013"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternates

1. add `tr -d '\n'` at the end of echo+grep+sed pipeline.
2. `{ entire-echo-grep-sed-pipeline ; echo , 2013 ; } | xargs echo` (This however, will add a space before ,)